# Use Automator/Applescript to crop filenames after certain character?

Tags: applescript, automator

I have a folder containing about 5000 files with names like:

```
    Invoice 10.1 (2012) (Digital) (4-Attachments).pdf 
    Carbon Copy - Invoice No 02 (2010) (2 Copies) (Filed).pdf
    01.Reciept #04 (Scanned-Copy).doc
```

I want to rename these files by removing everything from the first bracket onwards, so they look like this:

```
    Invoice 10.1.pdf
    Carbon Copy - Invoice No 02.pdf
    01.Reciept #04.doc
```

I have found lots of scripts that will remove the last x letters, but nothing that will crop from a particular character.

Ideally I would like to use Automator, but I'm guess this might too complex for it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
set xxx to (choose folder)
tell application "Finder"
set yyy to every paragraph of (do shell script "ls " & POSIX path of xxx)
repeat with i from 1 to count of yyy
    set theName to item i of yyy
    set name of (file theName of xxx) to (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of theName & " | sed s'/ (.*)//'")
end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

The [code posted by @adayzone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10043562/990363) will work, but there is no need to use `sed` for this – plain AppleScript will do, using `offset`:

```
set fullString to "Invoice 10.1 (2012) (Digital) (4-Attachments).pdf"
set trimmedString to text 1 thru ((offset of "(" in fullString) - 1) of fullString
-- trim trailing spaces
repeat while trimmedString ends with " "
    set trimmedString to text 1 thru -2 of trimmedString
end repeat
```

this returns “Invoice 10.1". To split the file name into the name and extension, and re-add the extension, you can use *System Events*’ Disk-File-Folder suite, which will provide the handy `name extension` property you can store and re-add after trimming the name.

Assuming you use some Automator action to get the files to be processed, the full processing workflow would be to add an AppleScript action after the file selection part with the following code:

```
repeat with theFile in (input as list)
    tell application "System Events"
        set theFileAsDiskItem to disk item ((theFile as alias) as text)
        set theFileExtension to name extension of theFileAsDiskItem
        set fullString to name of theFileAsDiskItem
        -- <insert code shown above here>
        set name of theFileAsDiskItem to trimmedString & "." & theFileExtension
    end tell
end repeat
```

If you want your Automator workflow to process the files any further, you will also have to create a list of aliases to the renamed files and return that from the AppleScript action (instead of `input`, which, of course, is not valid anymore).